# Matlab - Using IFELSE statement to solve quadratic formula

Tags: matlab, if-statement, quadratic

[image]

I need help getting this script started. Your help will be greatly appreciated! Again, I don't want the answer but rather how to start this script so it can spark ideas. Thank you once again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if a == 0
    if b == 0
        if c == 0
            % Case 1)
        else
            % Case 2)
        end
    elseif c ~= 0
        % Case 3)
    end

    % Case 5: a==0, b~=0, c==0
    % Linear equation through origin

else
    % Case 4)
end
```

Comment: Okay, I see what you did with setting up the cases. How would you go about setting up the equations? Would you set it up for each case? Or before the ifstatement?